# Node.js - Only displaying last element in JSON rsponse

Tags: node.js, json, parsing, pug

I am parsing a JSON response generated by a remote API. I iterate through the response and store the desired fields in values. The I create my homeCard elements from pug template and pass it the values. This issue with this is that it only displays the last element in the json response (Sexy Beach 3). How do I alter my code so that a homecard is created each time I pass through the loop?

```
    const axios = require('axios');

axios({
  url: "https://api-v3.igdb.com/games",
  method: 'GET',
  headers: {
      'Accept': 'application/json',
      'user-key': 'user-key'
  },
  data: "fields name,summary,url,popularity;sort popularity desc;limit 4;"
})
  .then(response => {
    /* GET home page. */
    router.get('/', (req, res, next) => {
      res.render('index', { pageId: 'index',
                        title: 'Homepage',
                        cards: homeCards
        });
    });
    //Iterate through the JSON array
    let r = response.data; 
    for (i=0; i<r.length; ++i){
      //create homecards with 
        var title = r[i].name;
        var description = r[i].summary;
        var link = r[i].url;
        var homeCards = [
          {
            title: title,
            link: link,
            description: description,
          },
          {
            title: title,
            link: link,
            description: description,
          },
          {
            title: title,
            link: link,
            description: description,
          },
          {
            title: title,
            link: link,
            description: description,
          },
          ]
        console.log(title, description, link);
      }

          })
  .catch(err => {
      console.error(err);
  });
```

Here is the JSON response

[image]

Comment: *"Here is the JSON response"* Please post code, markup, data such as JSON, etc. **as text**, not as a *picture* of text. Why: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/157247 Also, the JSON posted is invalid (missing a leading `[`), but I figure you just cut off the picture...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are assigning the same value to the homecards array object,also overwrites the same array every iteration.
You have to declare the homecards array outside the loop and push the objects to it.

```
    const axios = require('axios');

axios({
  url: "https://api-v3.igdb.com/games",
  method: 'GET',
  headers: {
      'Accept': 'application/json',
      'user-key': 'user-key'
  },
  data: "fields name,summary,url,popularity;sort popularity desc;limit 4;"
})
  .then(response => {
    /* GET home page. */
    router.get('/', (req, res, next) => {
      res.render('index', { pageId: 'index',
                        title: 'Homepage',
                        cards: homeCards
        });
    });
    //Iterate through the JSON array
    let r = response.data; 
    var homeCards = [];
    for (i=0; i<r.length; ++i){
      //create homecards with 
        var title = r[i].name;
        var description = r[i].summary;
        var link = r[i].url;
         homeCards.push({
            title: title,
            link: link,
            description: description,
          });
        console.log(title, description, link);
      }

          })
  .catch(err => {
      console.error(err);
  });
```

Comment: Or better yet, use `map`. You can also use shorthand properties and destructuring. `const homeCards = response.data.map(({name: title, summary: description, url: link}) => ({title, link, description}));`

Comment: @Sharvin K Your solution worked. All the json is parsed into the cards, but now an extra card is being rendered with noting on it. I declared var homeCards = [4] outside the for loop

Comment: @T.J. Crowder Does this declaration go inside or outside the for loop? I declared it isnide and got the error: hoemCards is not defined on line 33

Comment: Nevermind. I fixed the issue. I declare var homeCards = []

Comment: @Gabriel - No loop at all: https://pastebin.com/v5rEqvKG (Well, the loop is the `map` call...)